# Dealing with false positives in binary image segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm working on a model to identify bodies of water in satellite imagery. I've modified [this](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models/blob/master/examples/binary%20segmentation%20(camvid).ipynb) example a bit to use a set of ~600 images I've labeled, and it's working quite well for true positives - it produces an accurate mask for imagery tiles with water in it. However, it produces some false-positives as well, generating masks for tiles that have no water in them whatsoever - tiles containing fields, buildings or parking lots, for instance. I'm not sure how to provide this sort of negative feedback to the model - adding false-positive images to the training set with an empty mask is having no effect, and I tried a training set made up of only false-positives, which just produces random noise, making me think that empty masks have no effect on this particular network.

I also tried training a binary classification network from a couple of examples I found to classify tiles as water/notwater. It doesn't seem to be working with a good enough accuracy to use a first-pass filter, with about 5k images per class. I used OSM label-maker for this, and the image sets aren't perfect - there are some water tiles in the non-water set and vice-versa, but even the training set isn't getting good accuracy (~.85 at best).

Is there a way to provide negative feedback to the binary image segmentation model? Should I use a larger training set? I'm kinda stuck here without an ability to provide negative feedback, and would appreciate any pointers on how to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your 600 image training set is probably not big enough to train sufficient classifier. I'd try augmenting it or label a lot more images if you can manage. 600 samples is unfortunately not enough for most deep learning applications.